# Statistics::Regression cannot run univariate regression?

Tags: perl, statistics, regression

I'm using the Perl module of `Statistics::Regression`. It runs multi-variate regressions fine. However, if I only supply one regressor in the constructor

```
my $reg = Statistics::Regression->new("Sample Regression", ['X']);
```

It complains with this message:

```
Statistics::Regression:new: Cannot run a regression without at least two variables.
```

Do people have the same problem? The error message is not clearly worded so that I interpreted as if I'm not supplying the response variable. But that turns out not to be the case as based on its doc and some sample scripts I tested on the side, the list reference in the constructor should only include regressors.

IN any case, how do you run a single variable regression (no constant term) using this module? (I know `Statistics::OLS` can do that but for simplicity I would like this module to work. At any rate, feels like a stupid omission if it truly cannot handle that.) Thx!

Comment: Given the description says "Regression.pm is a **multivariate** linear regression package", I don't see how you're going to get it to do univariate regressions.

Comment: @CanSpice, Ok, fair enough. If you make that as an answer, I'll check you. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [module's description](http://search.cpan.org/~iawelch/Statistics-Regression-0.53/Regression.pm#DESCRIPTION) reads:

> Regression.pm is a multivariate linear regression package.

Given this, it seems unlikely that you'll be able to get it to do univariate regressions.

You could try emailing [the author](http://search.cpan.org/~iawelch/), though. It's been four years since `Statistics::Regression` was released to CPAN so he might have stopped supporting it (or it's in such a good state that it doesn't need more releases), but it's worth a shot getting his opinion. He might have some idea as to patching it to handle univariate regressions.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work for univariate, specify a constant, like this:
(include's first argument is y, second is [ constant, x ]). You can also specify 0 as the constant if you don't want the intercept

```
my $reg=Statistics::Regression->new("Title", ["Intercept", "Slope"]);
 
$reg->include(1.3, [1.0, 1.0]);
$reg->include(2.9, [1.0, 2.0]);
$reg->include(4.2, [1.0, 3.0]);
$reg->include(5.4, [1.0, 4.0]);
```

Find a detailed explanation in this [blog](http://perlgems.blogspot.com/2012/07/performing-linear-regression-in-perl.html)